# How to make pictures smaller?

Tags: feature-request, images

The pictures I place into questions and answers appear very huge. They are always scaled to the width of the text that is good for the wide, low pictures but not for the narrow and high pictures. Some screenshot may span over all screen creating the wrong impression that the contributor proves something crucial for humanity or at least SO community with that figure. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642194/align-image-to-the-center-of-another-image-android).

Would it be possible to have an option to scale the picture half width of text area and use another half for text like in Wikipedia? Or at least have an option like "half text area width centered?". These should be options for the text editor, not for the viewer.

Comment: Just use `img` tags and set the `width` attribute as a workaround. Plain Markdown doesn't support image scaling

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, just add an **s**, **m** or **l** (lowercase) at the end of the imgur link before the ".png".

For example, the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32.png can be made:

**S**mall:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32s.png]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32s.png

---

**M**edium:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32m.png]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32m.png

---

**L**arge:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32l.png]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32l.png

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the [Thumbnail Uploader](https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader) Stack Exchange browser extension.

[image: Screen shot]

This will use the image size you select via the radio button or at a size you specify. It will also create a link to the full size image if you want.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about this one. I'll remember it for the next time someone asks about photo uploading / sizing. ;)