# Provide an option to resize/link to the original image when uploading an image

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader, image-size-modifiers

Uploading an image now put an (original size) image linked to itself. IMHO, it feels like a [misfeature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393199/) to me.

Usually, I don't want the image to be linked to anywhere. Sometimes but not always, I want the image to be linked to the original image *if I resize the image*. Otherwise, I just want to get the resized image without link.

Currently, with `[![alt-text][1]][1]` format:

1. If I don't want it to be linked, I have to remove the outer brackets (not a big issue)
2. If I want to resize it, I have to copy-paste `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/example.png`, change the reference number and the outer link to `[2]`, and finally add size suffix (a bit troublesome if I have to do it many times)

This is the proposed changes to the image uploader popup:

1. Add a checkbox whether to link to the image or not
2. Add an option to resize: large/medium/small

---

Originally proposed by [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281218/can-we-make-imgur-resized-pictures-default-to-linking-to-the-full-image#comment913551_281218) on [Can we make imgur-resized pictures default to linking to the full image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281218/)

> I'd rather that they just added a "display size: small|medium|full" option in the upload window. This wouldn't fix things for edits but I don't think forcing the link is necessary. Honestly, even just forcing medium for all images and letting people override to remove the size constraint or make the image smaller would be acceptable.

Comment: There [was a script for this](https://stackapps.com/questions/3507/thumbnail-uploader), I never tried it, not sure if it still works. The thumbnail selector would be great. An option to not link, though... links to same size images aren't really intrusive enough to be an issue, are they? Having more people not post links would actually kind of bug me, because then I'd always be checking to see if there was a higher res image and the person just unnecessarily decided not to link it.