# Please add image size options to markdown help

Tags: feature-request, images, image-size-modifiers

The [markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) page for images says nothing on how to make small, medium and large sizes as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165795/how-to-make-pictures-smaller).  This info is very handy.  Please add it.

Comment: If you're going to do that, you may as well go the whole hog & include how to set 'display' & 'clickthrough' sizes simultaneously - [Sizing images in posts - original size in link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385664/276027)

Comment: btw - this is a more comprehensive size guide - [Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74312/276027)